# YARD ⇒ how to add custom output to several methods descriptions basing on one DSL statement in YARD plugin

Tags: ruby, yard

I have the problem writing YARD plugin for the following DSL:

```
class MyClass
  my_dsl :do_it, :do_other
  def do_it
    # do it
  end
  def do_other
    # do other
  end
  def do_unrelated
    # do unrelated
  end
end
```

Now I want to add notes to those methods’ documentation snippets, which are “influenced” by DSL `my_dsl`. Within `my_dsl` handler the scope is totally different (I don’t want to add some new docs, I want to extend already existing for methods.)

So I decided to use [Proxy](http://rubydoc.info/docs/yard/YARD/CodeObjects/Proxy) code object inside `MyDSLHandler#process` to mark the needed methods for delayed future postprocessing (which is to occur within built-in `MethodHandler` on `def do_it ; … ; end`.) It looks like:

```
class MyDSLHandler < YARD::Handlers::Ruby::DSLHandler
  handles method_call(:my_dsl)
  namespace_only

  def process
    statement.parameters.each { |astnode|
      mthd = astnode.jump(:string_content).source if astnode.respond_to? :jump
      obj = YARD::CodeObjects::Proxy.new(namespace, "\##{mthd}", :method)
      register(obj)
      obj[:my_dsl_params] << {
        name: mthd,
        file: statement.file, line: statement.line # I need this!
      }
    }
  end
end
```

Now the problem is that the `Proxy` object is derived from plain `Object`, not from `YARD::CodeObjects::Base` and therefore has no `[]=` method defined:

```
[warn]: Load Order / Name Resolution Problem on MyClass#do_it:
[warn]: -
[warn]: Something is trying to call [] on object MyClass#do_it before it has been recognized.
[warn]: This error usually means that you need to modify the order in which you parse files
[warn]: so that MyClass#do_it is parsed before methods or other objects attempt to access it.
[warn]: -
[warn]: YARD will recover from this error and continue to parse but you *may* have problems
[warn]: with your generated documentation. You should probably fix this.
[warn]: -
[error]: Unhandled exception in Yard::Handlers::MyDSLHandler:
[error]:   in `example_mydsl.rb`:5:

    5: my_dsl :do_it, :do_other

[error]: ProxyMethodError: Proxy cannot call method #[] on object 'MyClass#do_it'
```

How am I supposed to store some values from current context to `Proxy` object, so that they would be available during object real instantiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was able to resolve it.

The use of `Proxy` here is not supposed. The `CodeObject`s have a pretty peculiarity: they are “silent” singletons. Hence, as you have defined an object via `CodeObject.new`, all the forthcoming calls to `new` on the same object (according to `Registry`) will be re-mapped to the existing one.

Therefore in my case I simply create the `MethodObject`:

```
m = "#{astnode.jump(:string_content).source[1..-1]}";
obj = YARD::CodeObjects::MethodObject.new(namespace, "#{m}")
```

and then I do what I want on the newly created object:

```
obj.my_dsl_params = { :win => true, :mthd => "#{m}", … }
```

The object within method definition parse will `merge` these properties with it’s own. The only need is either to register an object with `register(obj)` or to return it from `process` method for system registering.